# Open a downloadable file

Tags: ocaml

I use `open_in` to open a local file with its path:

```
let f = open_in "/Users/SoftTimur/file.txt" in
...
```

Now, I would like to open a downloadable file with its URL:

```
let f = open_in "http://caml.inria.fr/distrib/ocaml-4.02/ocaml-4.02-refman.txt" in
...
```

returns an error `Fatal error: exception Sys_error("http://caml.inria.fr/distrib/ocaml-4.02/ocaml-4.02-refman.txt: No such file or directory")`.

Does anyone know which function I could use to open such a downloadable file? Do I have to first download it to local (how to do that by OCaml?)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, there are plenty of libraries in OCaml that can deal with `http` protocol in particular and with network communications in general. None of them will provide a function of type `string -> in_channel` as the `in_channel` type is an abstraction owned by OCaml. The language doesn't allow us to create our own implementations of the channel type<sup>1</sup>.

The libraries, that I know and used are:

1. [cohttp](https://github.com/mirage/ocaml-cohttp) - asynchronous library for http client and servers;
2. [ocurl](http://ocurl.forge.ocamlcore.org) - a binding to the libcurl;
3. [ocamlnet](http://projects.camlcity.org/projects/ocamlnet.html) - all things network and even much more;

Presumably there are others, please feel free to edit this answer and add them.

I personally prefer asynchronous monadic `cohttp`, but it is easier to start with `ocamlnet`, that is also an excellent library, that has lots of features. This is how to play with it in the OCaml toplevel:

```
# #use "topfind"
# #require "netclient";
# module Client = Nethttp_client.Convenience
# let ocamldoc = Client.http_get "http://caml.inria.fr/distrib/ocaml-4.02/ocaml-4.02-refman.txt";;
```

Before starting the playing, make sure that you installed it with

```
opam install ocamlnet
```

---

**Footnotes:**

1. at least in pure OCaml, it is possible to create it from C, but I doubt if someone will pursue in this direction, it doesn't worth.

Comment: Thank you for this... One problem is that I will transfer all my OCaml code to JS code by `js_of_ocaml`. I tried the solution of `ocamlnet`, with `js_of_ocaml`, it missed lots of primitives...

Comment: then the only choice for you is `cohttp+lwt`

Comment: I succeeded in running `cohttp+lwt` over a txt file staring with `http://`. However, my generated text file generally starts with [blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob), it seems that `cohttp+lwt` don't support this schema.

Comment: And still, `js_of_ocaml` on OCaml files returns lots of missing primitives such as `lwt_libev_init`, `lwt_libev_io_stop`, `lwt_unix_blit`...

Comment: js_of_ocaml already has [XmlHttpRequest.get](http://ocsigen.org/js_of_ocaml/2.7/api/XmlHttpRequest#VALget) that does what you want. No need to use other libraries.

Answer (score 1):

In Ocaml this is an C fopen call, no way to do it with a http source scheme.

You will have to download the file first, use one of the usual download tools wget or curl which are used in your linux package manager as well. `Sys.command` is your friend to do this.

It would be not too hard writing a module that checks the file name for a "schema:" like prefix, and taking appropriate action.

Maybe look at the opam sources for inspiration?

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know which function I could use to open such a downloadable file?

Install the `wget` program for your Linux distro and use the `Unix` library when you compile and you can use:

```
let open_url_in = Unix.open_process_in("wget -O - " ^ url)
```

This runs the `wget` program with `-O o` asking it to output the downloaded file to stdout which `open_process_in` reads into your process as the resulting channel.

> Do I have to first download it to local (how to do that by OCaml?)?

No.